# Related to the The US Communications Act / Title 47 CFR: Would a license under one part be jepordized by a violation in another part?

Tags: contract-law, fcc, title

The question is slightly different at the end but doesn't make complete sense without the intervening text.

A bit of background. I have been a Licensed Amateur Radio Operator (Title 47 CFR Part 97) for 20 years.

I recently ran into a legal and ethical situation where I was Sub-sub-contracted to a vendor who wanted me to violate Part 90 (Licensed Business/Industrial) of the same CFR by programming radios that should have been frequency coordinated and licensed for use.

I informed the Vendor what needed to be done for licensing (Form 601), and offered to do the work of locating non-interfereing channels that would support their use. I hoped to make compliance the easy route. Normally this Would be handled by a coordinator during the application process.

Their answer was 'we do this all the time and have no intention of asking the client to get licenses.' That being the ethical portion, I declined to unknowinly open the end user to potential fines and subject licensed users to interference and left the project.

I am fairly certain that asking me to violate a law breaches any contract (only a verbal was in place for this work).

The question is if had I instead provided the assistance would my existing Radio License be in jeopardy and would I have assumed liability for damages by that action?

Comment: Just as a point of information I did start research when this came up and determined the client does have some (maybe 1%) of their locations with current or 10 year expired licenses when the radios were provided by a different vendor.